# VLC in Raspberry Pi won't play h264 video file

Tags: raspberry-pi, h.264, vlc

I installed the latest version of vlc on my Raspberry Pi 2 today with `sudo apt-get install vlc`, which worked just fine. However, when I try to play my video.h264 file using it, it only plays the first frame of the video and then it stops. I started vlc from terminal by using `vlc video.h264` and this is the error message I got:

```
VLC media player 2.0.3 Twoflower (revision 2.0.2-93-g77aa89e)
[0x1868f0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[h264 @ 0x1cbcd60] max_analyze_duration reached
[h264 @ 0x1cbcd60] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be innacurate
[0x1df8378] main input error: Invalid PCR value in ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_) PCR !
[0x1dd4f40] xcb_xv vout display error: no available XVideo adaptor
```

I have looked up the two error messages on several places but none of them seem to have any useful solutions (they all happen with very different context than mine, usually much more complicated). It seems like a pretty basic fix since all I did was install VLC and try to play my video file. I also tried the same video file on VLC in my Macbook Pro and it works and plays just fine. It just doesn't work on my Raspberry Pi's VLC player. Please help! :)

Thank you!

Comment: I solved this problem. VLC doesn't make use of the GPU (hardware acceleration) to play video, and the raspberry pi doesn't have enough processing power to play video using only software. In order to play video, you need to compile a hardware accelerated version of VLC yourself on your RPi and maybe even overclock it. This will allow for VLC to play video. Here's how to compile hardware accelerated VLC on Rpi: http://www.oblivion-software.de/index.php?id=56&type=98

Comment: Thanks for the update. However your question might be better suited for http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The updated link for the first comment: https://www.oblivion-software.de/index.php?id=62

Comment: An archived link from the third comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20201120165746/https://www.oblivion-software.de/index.php?id=62